# Slide Divs on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [this example](https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/) to slide divs in on scroll. I've essentially copied and pasted the code, then switched the class name that I want to slide in before I begin tinkering with the code. But, it doesn't work at all. Nothing appears in the console log, so no syntax errors or missing semicolons. I'm completely stuck, if anyone can point out of what I'm missing, that would be sweet.

```js
(function($) {

  /**
   * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
   * Licensed under the MIT license.
   * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
   *
   * @author Sam Sehnert
   * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
   *     the user visible viewport of a web browser.
   *     only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
   */

  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {
    
      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;
    
    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };
    
})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var gallery = $("#gallery");

gallery.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("already-visible"); 
    } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {  
  gallery.each(function(i, el) {
        var el = $(el);
        if (el.visible(true)) {
            el.addClass("come-in"); 
        } 
    });  
});
```

```css
.panel {
  padding: 8% 0;
}

#gallery {
  height: 1385px;
  height: 211vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#images-gallery {
  display: grid;
  height: 1385px;
  height: 211vh;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.gallery-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .5);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

#lightbox img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px #111;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}

#image-one {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/HXfG735/tattoo.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-two {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/kBJrryt/7ab34470-9318-4fc1-a6da-656ca31399c5.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-three {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/SKCnT4d/b19aaf2a-84cf-42b4-9ccd-6205ca1be395.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}

#image-four {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/xF4Qv50/b5d6695b-2142-42cc-8eef-2963311edfd6.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}

#image-five {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/wS1N4M8/41fa959a-3c96-45d7-9e2c-8cbf78866b1a.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}

#image-six {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/0rHYr7K/2828c725-d0d8-48b5-8f75-57bccd6830af.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-seven {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/2M2fw9h/a430dbb8-6006-499f-8583-814da647838a.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-eight {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/0nY3VDG/d1ecf205-6b1b-4a1a-b94b-7d75aa177464.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 60%;
}

#image-nine {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/QYf6vDY/48a63fe2-066b-42d1-9211-040c6977ceff.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 40%;
}

#image-ten {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/7RdJqgP/ce30fff2-1679-403f-8431-c6be4f8b1466.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 80%;
}

#image-eleven {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/FnHSXFk/d1469435-7683-4fc0-975b-571b8d6f3bda.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 40%;
}

#image-twelve {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/BtJxDc7/24b54530-710f-4173-a32a-36bd24a496e0.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
}

.come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}

.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  /* So they look staggered */
}

.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes come-in {
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery" class="panel">
  <div id="images-gallery">
    <div id="image-one" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/HXfG735/tattoo.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-two" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/kBJrryt/7ab34470-9318-4fc1-a6da-656ca31399c5.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-three" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/SKCnT4d/b19aaf2a-84cf-42b4-9ccd-6205ca1be395.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-four" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/xF4Qv50/b5d6695b-2142-42cc-8eef-2963311edfd6.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-five" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/wS1N4M8/41fa959a-3c96-45d7-9e2c-8cbf78866b1a.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-six" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/0rHYr7K/2828c725-d0d8-48b5-8f75-57bccd6830af.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-seven" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/2M2fw9h/a430dbb8-6006-499f-8583-814da647838a.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eight" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/0nY3VDG/d1ecf205-6b1b-4a1a-b94b-7d75aa177464.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-nine" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/QYf6vDY/48a63fe2-066b-42d1-9211-040c6977ceff.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-ten" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/7RdJqgP/ce30fff2-1679-403f-8431-c6be4f8b1466.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-eleven" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/FnHSXFk/d1469435-7683-4fc0-975b-571b8d6f3bda.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="image-twelve" class="gallery-item">
      <a href="https://i.ibb.co/BtJxDc7/24b54530-710f-4173-a32a-36bd24a496e0.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It gives me errors on the console, please take a look at your console again.

Comment: Fixed. No errors, just blank - exactly like my webpage (with the Jquery code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. Everything is working as it should. You're just missing to set `.come-in` and `.already-visible` to `opacity: 1;`. They're set to `opacity: 0;` by default so you need to transition them to `opacity: 1` when they are already visible or "coming-in".

```
.come-in {
    transform: translateY(150px);
    animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}

.already-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    animation: none;
}
```